# How did I get this bit of reputation after I hit the repcap?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I hit the repcap on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) on the 20th, so I should only have earned 165 rep. (Does that not make sense? I had an accepted answer, so that's an extra 15 that doesn't count. And I started a bounty for 50, so that's 165.)

[Here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/33591/mithrandir?tab=reputation) it says I got 167:

[image]

And here you can see a random +2 in the middle from a specific question that I asked then (maybe someone will add a FHRC):

[image]

And my /reputation page doesn't believe it happened:

[image]

[image]

(^When I took this screenshot, on SFF it said I have 5902 rep.)

## How did I get this +2?

Comment: Did you downvote 2 answers (-1 point each)? Have you had an edit approved (+2 points).

Comment: @Valorum no, to both

Comment: If I had to guess, it's probably somethin to do with DVK removing his upvote; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147924/what-was-the-ludicrous-patents-office/147925#comment379154_147925

Comment: Possibly you had a down vote (-2) that was immediately reversed.

Comment: If you check the box labelled "show removed posts" at the bottom of your reputation page, you should be able to see if any removed votes/posts are the culprit

Comment: Did you delete a post which had been downvoted?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Don't think so, maybe an bot did? Although I didn't think that I had any left.

Comment: I just checked and none of your deleted SFF posts were deleted in the last month.

Comment: @Valorum - a valid guess but incorrect. I intended to unupvote but ended up being distracted and never did

Comment: Hmm. My latest guess is that a user was removed during the same day and that a downvote got cancelled.

Comment: @Valorum I didn't get any downvotes on that Q though, and it would show up on it's own then

Comment: @Mithrandir - It's certainly a mystery. Use the contact us button below to attract a CM.

Comment: Did you accept an answer in that time?

Comment: @Mooz nope. It would show up as a different post in that chart, anyway, I think.

Comment: Have seen such question on metaSO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Between the upvote that gave you the extraneous 2 reputation and the one before it, you *had* cast two downvotes. They were both on the same post, and they were both retracted shortly after you cast them. Since we collapse upvote/downvote pairs that occur on the same day, both of those were hidden from your reputation history the moment they were retracted.

However, your overall reputation for the day still sat at 198, because retracting a downvote does not refresh *your* reputation cap for the day. Only a full reputation recalc can do that, and you hadn't experienced anything within that time frame which would have triggered one of those. So when the next vote came in, it saw "198" and thought it needed to give you 2 more reputation, which it did... for a bit.

Once the next event occurred on December 25th to qualify your account for recalculation, the system caught onto this oddity and corrected it. Anything to do with that 2 reputation was gone at that point, and your reputation with its history was now correct.

Comment: Huh. I don't remember anything about those o_o. But okay then!