# I earned I Have A Little Dreidel for getting an upvote on a question, without doing anything

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

Here on Meta.SE I received the [*I Have A Little Dreidel*](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/i-have-a-little-dreidel) hat when I got an upvote on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288558/how-did-i-get-this-bit-of-reputation-after-i-hit-the-repcap) last night, before I did anything - the first thing that I did on SE was go to the Puzzling, and then I clicked on notifications. When I clicked on the hats, I saw that I had earned IHALD on Meta.SE, after getting an upvote. I didn't *do anything*. Yet I received the hat.

Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or is it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: Did you cast any votes after December **23th**, 10am UTC? There was a bug in the Dreidel hat, so you might not have received it ±10 minutes after the action that triggered it, but it has been awarded retroactively.

Comment: @Glorfindel Possibly. I don't remember. Anyway, I should have gotten it on Puzzling, AI, and Scifi also - I voted there, pretty sure. And I didn't.

Comment: You've voted on 9 posts as seen here http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/294691/mithrandir?tab=topactivity

Comment: You can still check your votes and their times in your profile.

Comment: @BhargavRao That's now. Last night I hadn't.

Comment: @Glorfindel So yes, I voted. And it looks like I didn't vote on the others, which is... Odd for me :P

Comment: Ah, a typical PICNIC (problem in chair, not in computer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not get the hat just for being upvoted. You have to make an *active* contribution to the site.

The probable source of your confusion is that because of a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288738/295232), the Dreidel hat wasn't awarded when intended (December 23th, 10am UTC). Shortly after the fix was made, the hats were awarded retroactively. So there could be 24 hours between the trigger and the awarding of the hat, instead of the normal 10 minutes maximum.